# I'm having issues with aligning elements (Java GUI / Swing);

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, alignment

I'm attempting to align TextField vertically next to some labels, however the alignment isn't working for the TextField in which it does the Labels

At first I thought it was size miscalculations however that's not the case, I've tried aligning left and right panels to their according sides (EAST and WEST) however that didn't work either.

```
JPanel leftPanel = new JPanel();
leftPanel.setBounds(0,0, 100, 300 );
JPanel rightPanel = new JPanel();
rightPanel.setBounds(100, 0, 50, 300);

JLabel fiftyNoteLabel = new JLabel("TOTAL $50s");
JLabel twentyNoteLabel = new JLabel("TOTAL $20s");

JTextField fiftyNoteText = new JTextField("0");
JTextField twentyNoteText = new JTextField("0");

main.add( leftPanel );
main.add( rightPanel );

leftPanel.add( fiftyNoteLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH );
leftPanel.add( twentyNoteLabel, BorderLayout.NORTH );
rightPanel.add( fiftyNoteText, BorderLayout.NORTH );
rightPanel.add( twentyNoteText, BorderLayout.NORTH );

main.setVisible( true );
leftPanel.setVisible( true );
rightPanel.setVisible( true );
```

Comment: Better to use a single layout for this, like `GridBagLayout` or `GridLayout` depending on your needs

Answer (score 0):

Ooops, turns out Java handles components being added sequentially, I was attempting to alter the position by changing the alignment of the element. However I was supposed to be adding the elements in order.

EG. LABEL -> TEXTFIELD = "Hello" [     ]